# Run Chromium with fake webcam and real micro

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I can run the Google Chrome with the fake webcam using this command:

`$ google-chrome-stable --use-fake-device-for-media-stream --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=video.mjpeg`

This works fine, but I can only use fake audio sources using this configuration. How to run Chromium/Google Chrome with fake video stream and real audio stream?

Also you can use any Python modules you want.

Comment: Would you be ok with a puppeteer based solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` it is not possible, [Chrome will always use fake audio](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/d0a8b6b6069cd4353153bd039098d4df55daeb24/content/browser/media/audio_input_stream_broker.cc#LC91):

```c
if (base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(
        switches::kUseFakeDeviceForMediaStream)) {
  params_.set_format(media::AudioParameters::AUDIO_FAKE);
}
```

Use a virtual webcam and your real microphone instead.
A quick selection from searching:

- [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/), Windows/macOS/Linux
- [OBS Virtualcam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/), plugin for [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/), Windows/macOS/Linux
- [Syphon Virtual Webcam](https://troikatronix.com/plugin/syphon-virtual-webcam/), plugin for [Isadora](https://troikatronix.com/), macOS

Comment: AlterCam is also good to use. and following is a good demo.
https://github.com/spite/virtual-webcam/